# Zimbra REST request with multiple queries

Tags: zimbra

I want to make a query to the Zimbra server with many senders :

```
http://zimbra.server.com/home/plinard/?fmt=xml&query=from:mail1@gmail.com mail2@gmail.com
```

It returns me juste the emails from mail1@gmail.com

I tried this too

```
http://zimbra.server.com/home/plinard/?fmt=xml&query=from:mail1@gmail.com&from:mail2@gmail.com
```

same result...

Thnx in advance

Comment: Have you tried with `query=from:mail1@gmail.com+from:mail2@gmail.com`?

Comment: Yes, not working, but take à look at my own answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution :)

```
http://zimbra.server.com/home/plinard/?fmt=xml&query=from:(mail1@gmail.com or mail2@gmail.com)
```

This link contains the Zimbra's Query Language

http://www.zimbra.com/desktop/help/en_US/Search/query_language_description.htm

Cheers ^^